# Script is supposed to teleport Player A to Player B and vice-versa (swap character's positions), but only teleports one of them on top of the other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm not at all experienced with Unity and C#. This code seems to look right. I don't really know what I need to put here to provide more context, so I will do so if the need arises

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace ModScripts
{
    public class TeleporterScript : MonoBehaviour, IUseItem
    {
        public float maxRange = 5f;

        [SerializeField]
        private GameObject playerObject;
        private Collider[] colliders;
        private GameObject target;
        private float distancia;

        // UseItem executes right when player presses a specific key on keyboard
        public void UseItem(Transform position, Quaternion rotation)
        {
            // playerObject is supposed to be the player that used the item
            playerObject = position.gameObject;
            Instantiate(gameObject, position.position, rotation);
            CheckCollider();
        }

        void CheckCollider()
        {
            // Check the players using colliders
            // layer 15 is player A
            // layer 16 is player B
            int layerMask = (1 << 15) | (1 << 16);

            // Physics.OverlapSphere to make a limited range around the player
            colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, maxRange, layerMask);

            // Calculate distance between colliders[]
            foreach (Collider collider in colliders)
            {
                if (collider.gameObject.layer != playerObject.layer)
                {
                    // Calculate distance
                    distancia = Vector3.Distance(playerObject.transform.position, collider.transform.position);
                    
                    // If distance is bigger than maxRange
                    if (distancia > maxRange)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Teleport to target
                        target = collider.gameObject;                        
                        Teleport(target);
                    }
                }
            }
        }                  

        void Teleport(GameObject target)
        {
            // Debug.Log says the intended target
            Debug.Log(target.name);
            float elevation = 0f;

            // Get velocity of both karts
            Vector3 currentVelocity = playerObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity;
            Vector3 targetVelocity = target.GetComponentInParent<Rigidbody>().velocity;

            // Switch positions between kart that used item and target
            Vector3 tempPosition = new Vector3(playerObject.transform.position.x, playerObject.transform.position.y + elevation, playerObject.transform.position.z);           
            playerObject.transform.position = new Vector3(target.transform.position.x, target.transform.position.y + elevation, target.transform.position.z);
            target.transform.position = tempPosition;
            
            // Maintain velocity of karts
            playerObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = currentVelocity;
            target.GetComponentInParent<Rigidbody>().velocity = targetVelocity;
        }
    }
}
```

The code above teleports the player that uses the item into the position of the other player, as intended. However the other player doesn't change positions, leading to one player being on top of the other. I am using the unity kartgame demo if it is of any importance.